# How do you apply lace edging to a lute?

Tags: lutherie, lute

I'm building a baroque lute and I'd like to seal the soundboard edging using the "lace" method where a strip of parchment is glued along the edge to hide the soundboard/bowl seam.

I'd like to use this method, as opposed to the conventional inlaid strip or wood or other binding material, because the lace method is baroque-era appropriate and this is an experimental lute that I might have to take apart for repairs and removing the lace is a lot less destructive than removing inlay. This method is still used by a few modern luthiers, like mentioned in [this blog](https://schreinerlutesandguitars.blogspot.com/2012/01/thomas-mace-and-i-repair-johns-theorbo.html?m=0), but unfortunately, he doesn't describe how he reapplies the lace.

However, I'm not finding much documentation on how to actually apply a lace edging. I have a couple books on lute construction, but they both use the modern inlay method.

I know lace typically involves using sheep/goatskin parchment and glue (presumably hide), but not much else. However, there are a ton of other factors I'm unsure about.

Should I prepare the parchment by soaking it in water first? Since the bowl already has some finish on it, should I sand back a little of it for the glue to take purchase? Should I iron a fold in the parchment to help it wrap around the edge? How would I hold the parchment in place while the glue dries?

Comment: They might know more at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com

Comment: Where have you looked for answers so far? There seem to be a lot of details at https://schreinerlutesandguitars.blogspot.com/2012/01/thomas-mace-and-i-repair-johns-theorbo.html?m=0